# on duplicate key with a where condition

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to use a `WHERE` condition on an `INSERT INTO` statement that contains `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. An example of what I'm trying to achieve is below.

This SQL statement is being called by third-party software and we want to exclude some exports based on numerical values, in this case 2. So, when X != Y perform INSERT, if X == Y, don't.

```
INSERT INTO satellites (name, intname) VALUES ('%SATELLITE.NAME%','%SATELLITE.INTNAME%') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='%SATELLITE.NAME%',intname='%SATELLITE.INTNAME%'  WHERE '%SATELLITE.NAME%' != 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `SELECT` query rather than `VALUES`. Then you can add a condition to ignore the name

```
INSERT INTO satellites (name, intname)
SELECT '%SATELLITE.NAME%' AS name, '%SATELLITE.INTNAME%'
FROM DUAL
HAVING name != 2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), intname = VALUES(intname)
```

Note that in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause you don't need to specify the assignment to the unique key column, since it's not going to change (since that's what is duplicate). But I didn't know which one is the unique key, so I didn't remove it.

`DUAL` is a placeholder for a table name when you're just selecting literal values.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the internal name from the satelites and search for it in your table

```
INSERT INTO satellites (name, intname) VALUES ('%SATELLITE.NAME%','%SATELLITE.INTNAME%') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='%SATELLITE.NAME%',intname=(SELECT intname FROM satellites  WHERE name != 2 ORDER BY intname LIMIT 1);
```